# MySQL MAX and MIN on Varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains 3 columns; `day_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`. `start_date` and `end_date` are varchar(8) in a format like this `HH:II:SS`. Sometimes dates can go over 24h in order to represent that something happened day after, for example: 25:20:01 is 01:20:01 but in a new day. **`day_id` is not unique, it repeats.** I need to get first and last event of a day, and this is my code:

```
SELECT day_id, 
MIN(start_date) as start_time, 
MAX(end_date) as end_date 
FROM events WHERE day_id IN ('day_1', 'day_2', 'day_3') 
GROUP BY day_id ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

It works as intended but I can't figure out why, how does MySQL know that `25:01:45` is larger than `20:21:09` since they are both varchars? The whole table is in `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation, running on MySQL server version 8.

Comment: It's just a straight string comparison, `'2'='2'` then `'5'>'0'` so `'25:01:45' > '20:21:09'`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Store data using the correct data type for that data. Here's what happens when you don't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac5fff/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a string comparison and it compares characters with their ascii value as you know. But it mainly works because it represents both single digits and two digits of time parameters as two digit representation. For example-

- `1:20:1` is represented as `01:20:01`
- `2:5:7` is represented as `02:05:07`

So, there will never be a time where `10:02:07` will come before `2:5:7`(since `1` < `2`) since `2:5:7` is `02:05:07` and `1` > `0`. Hence, it always works.

> Sometimes dates can go over 24h in order to represent that something
>   happened day after, for example: 25:20:01 is 01:20:01

So, if this `25` goes over 2 digits for some reason, then you will have problems. So, use the correct datatype to store it - `TIME`.

Comment: I don't know why but I thought that TIME can't hold values greater than 24h. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how does MySQL know that 25:01:45 is larger than 20:21:09?

Databases compare strings using a collation.  The default collation is alphabetical ordering.

So, MySQL knows that `'25'` > `'20'` in exactly the same way that we knows that the word `'BE'` comes after `'BA'` in the dictionary.